# Counting rows and query with AND with codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter

I'm trying to count the number of rows of a DB table that matches some criteria. Now I have the following code:

```
       $q = $this->db->get_where('info', array('city_id'=>$city->id));
       $count = $query->num_rows();
```

In the above code, `$count` will return the number of rows in `'info'` table that can matches `city_id` of `'info'` table with the `id` of the `'city'` table. In `'info'` table `'city_id'` is a FK.

But here I want to check two conditions, like:

1.Whether it matches the `fk(city_id)` of `info` table with the id of `'city'` table and
2. Whether it matches another field in the `info` table(lets say `name_id=1`);

Is there a way that I can join the two queries with AND?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another condition in second parameter of `get_where()` function.

`$q = $this->db->get_where('info', array('city_id'=>$city->id,'name_id'=>1));`